# How to flatten an array after db call in express?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using express to query my mongodb database using the native driver (not Mongoose.)

I am trying to do some data clean up after a MongoDB response. I don't mind if this could be achieved with MongoDB's aggregation query or some variation of it, for completeness the current query I'm using is: `collection.find({'make.name': req.params.make}, {'model.name': 1, 'submodel.body': 1, '_id': 0}).toArray();`

I have a response from mongodb:

```
[
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "3 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "3 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "3 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Convertible"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "model" : {
                            "name" : "2 Series"
                    },
                    "submodel" : {
                            "body" : "Coupe"
                    }
            }
    ]
```

which I would like to simplify to this:

```
[
 "model" : {
   "name": "2 Series"
  }

 "submodel" : {
   "body": ["Convertible", "Coupe"]
  }

 "model" : {
   "name": "3 Series"
  }

 "submodel" : {
   "body": ["Convertible", "Coupe"]
  }
]
```

New output:

```
{ "_id" : "M3", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "X5 eDrive", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "X5 M", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "M4 GTS", "submodel" : [ "Coupe" ] }
{ "_id" : "ActiveHybrid 5", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "X5", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "X6 M", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "i8", "submodel" : [ "Coupe" ] }
{ "_id" : "X4", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "5 Series Gran Turismo", "submodel" : [ "Hatchback" ] }
{ "_id" : "M4", "submodel" : [ "Coupe", "Convertible" ] }
{ "_id" : "5 Series", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "M6 Gran Coupe", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "X1", "submodel" : [ "SUV" ] }
{ "_id" : "3 Series eDrive", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "2 Series", "submodel" : [ "Coupe", "Convertible" ] }
{ "_id" : "6 Series Gran Coupe", "submodel" : [ "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "3 Series", "submodel" : [ "Wagon", "Sedan" ] }
{ "_id" : "Z4", "submodel" : [ "Convertible" ] }
{ "_id" : "6 Series", "submodel" : [ "Convertible", "Coupe" ] }
```

new output:

```
{
"_id": "2 Series",
"submodel": [
"Coupe",
"Convertible"
]
},
{
"_id": "3 Series",
"submodel": [
"Wagon",
"Sedan"
]
},
{
"_id": "3 Series Gran Turismo",
"submodel": [
"Hatchback"
]
},
{
"_id": "3 Series eDrive",
"submodel": [
"Sedan"
]
},
{
"_id": "4 Series",
"submodel": [
"Coupe",
"Convertible"
]
},
```

As you can see, model.name is a unique property, and "submodel.body" is now an array of unique body types.

How can I convert my array of non-unique models, to an array of unique models?

Current Query:

```
router.get('/test/:make', (req, res) => {
            var collection = db.get().collection('styles');
            collection.aggregate({
                $match: {
                    $or: [{
                            "make.niceName": req.params.make
                        },
                        {
                            "make.name": req.params.make
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$model.name",
                    "submodels": {
                        $addToSet: "$submodel.body"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $sort: {
                    _id: 1
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    models: "$_id",
                    submodel: 1,
                    _id: 0
                }
            }).toArray((err, docs) => {
                res.send(docs)
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation pipeline. `$addToSet` to get distinct `submodel` in each `model` group.

```
collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "make.name": req.params.make
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$model.name",
        submodel: {
            $addToSet: "$submodel.body"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: 1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        models: "$_id",
        submodel: 1,
        _id: 0
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried what you posted, and it worked! Just a small question about $project, can you help me construct it? check my edit for output. I just want to change "_id" to "models" and wrap submodels in it's own object.

Comment: where do I apply sort? I would like it to sort by model.name

Comment: I've added the `$sort` asc and updated `$project` to match the expected output.

Comment: models { name: __} is coming up as _id: ___, see edit

Comment: Please try again with the latest. It should be something like `{ "submodel" : [ "Coupe", "Convertible" ], "models" : "2 Series" }`

Comment: it still says "_id" : "2 Series"

Comment: Can i see your query pls ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you even see `_id` . I get `{ "models" : "2 Series" }` when I run your query. Btw, your `$group` (`submodels`) stage doesn't match `$group`(`submodel`) stage in answer.

Comment: Can you expand your comment ? I didn't understand what you mean by field equivalent

Comment: I want to include "$model.niceName" in the aggregation, the same way "$model.name" was included, $addToSet creates an Array, but I only need a field value.

Comment: Something like `{niceName:{$first:"$model.niceName"}}` More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/